# Webhook no longer working in EE 2.8.1

Tags: zoo-visitor, xid

I need help with a webhook on a client site which is not working since updating to 2.8.1 and ZooVisitor 1.3.32. When an order is fulfilled in the client's Shopify store it issues a JSON notification instructing EE+ZooVisitor to create/update a member account. Best I can tell Shopify is doing its part but something is no longer functioning correctly on the receiving EE end.

Could this be related to the new XID security requirements? I successfully fixed a form elsewhere on the site by adding the XID hash, but I have no clue where to add that to a webhook without a little guidance.

This was initially set up by an EE developer who has since gone AWOL and left me pretty much stranded. I would greatly appreciate any assistance anyone can offer to get this back up and running ASAP. I’m pretty familiar with EE but my background is primarily on the design side and this is apparently over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Problem was caused by new cross-site request forgery protections in EE. Setting the corresponding webhook action as csrf_exempt fixed it.